# I am trying to read data from input field and set it to in state but again and again getting error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
const OnBlurHandler = (e: React.FocusEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>): void =>  {
        const petnames = e.target.name;
        const petvalues = e.target.value;
}
```

> Property 'target' does not exist on type '(event: FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement, Element>) => void

Answer (score 1):

The event type is wrong, you should use `React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to figure out how to create the type you need:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwCYFMBmBDArgG3hgZzgCUUMBjGAXzjSghDgHIozKmBuAWACheAKADzAAdmCzwIIgEI4sUALwIA9ACo4AdQAWGeAS0RcSOAHMIcLSlYB+OKuVUAfIOWjxMRwEpuPZcrgBgQB6IaG8fnAAmoZw5BgitKLGMJZwMACeYChw6TEiKCjGAEbpFhAAblaiJnAVVmmpujBQwEUS2SIYICgAXOH+AJIJKcBEcQQoADRwwDBMBD0kbDAAdABiEORYBACilSIwABLxSDhWgocAKgCyADJD7jtn3QeOcAA+cFgiqGiihbx+nAAMoQaa5LCxeJfCYNbJob6UYBSNKZbJgejlYCoYqlUgUfBEFLZDJZODxEQQGC6ZEiPo8chSAjwHQ-M6yeQARkW+Mo6022z2KAOxzZ5yudweEieKBeHjgCjg-BQ+xgngVb0QvACjJEzK1PECcE63WmEWZLREJm1gXKGDkUzg5ua1RtVEVKuFq2pUBMKBgPioPiBAHkoHAMRVsdkUAAPMA4YDkWYRjBQLr++onOCsGDyYZoohoaA5QzhiAAdwSCJEyZgUnpuv1rNOKA5UAATAqlZ6DjzlvytrtVRcbvcxNLnl6vItyhBsRqAggbU34MvDYETY7nZbrRuAnaHWb-BbXRv3XBe96036A7wg4CeEI3BJajI5IoEC32R-OU4XC+HjeE6-gQAA1gIwgTpI77yEo35th+Hb-q40FeBwIG1BBPBAA)

```ts
import {default as React} from 'react';

(<input onBlur={/* What should go here? */}></input>);
//      ^^^^^^
// You can find the type you need by hovering over the attribute name:
// In this case, it's: React.FocusEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> | undefined

// So, you can use the function type provided by React as the type annotation:
const handleBlur1: React.FocusEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> = (event) =>  {
  const {
    name, // string
    value, // string
  }= event.target;
};

// Or provide explicit parameter and return types for your own funciton:
const handleBlur2 = (event: React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void =>  {
  const {
    name, // string
    value, // string
  }= event.target;
};

(<input onBlur={handleBlur1}></input>); // ok
(<input onBlur={handleBlur2}></input>); // ok
```